# eth.syncing returns a false but eth.blockNumber does not give the current block number

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I used "geth --syncmode light --http --http.api eth,web3" on Ubuntu to sync with the blockchain. After a while I checked eth.syncing and it retuned false. I then tried eth.blockNumber and compared it to see if it was the current block number. It was off by a few blocks. I waited some more time and tried eth.blockNumber and the result was exactly the same as before. I also tried w3.eth.get_block_number() and got the same result (as expected). I also tried w3.is_connected() and it returned "True"
Summary:
Node is fully synced.
Node is fully connected.
But it does not return current block number. It returns the same highest block number.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it so I can query the newly generated blocks? I am fairly new to eth blockchain. I started playing with his few weeks ago for the first time.